# Typo3 Form Elements "Login Form" Not Visible & showing error instead in 12 version

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-extensions, typo3-11.x

I am a beginner in Typo3 CMS.
I am getting issue in typo3 login form creating. its showing me error .
My system configurations are given bellow :

TYPO3 Version   12.0.0
Webserver   Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
PHP Version 8.1.13
Database (Default)  MySQL 10.3.37-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
Application Context Production
Composer mode   Enabled
Operating System    Linux 5.15.0-56-generic

I have tried this two way given bellow :-
1.I have tried by creating usergroup mapping that folder in login page .
2. fe-login extension is not available for version 12.

Comment: If you have a Composer-based installation require typo3/cms-felogin. When having a classic installation (with zip), you have to activate the extension "felogin" in the extension manager. Have you done this?

Comment: I have composer-base installation . How do I import typo3/cms-felogin this.Please guide (I followed with this command  ::: composer require typo3/cms-felogin)